# Get count of a column for duplicate data in another column

Tags: mysql

I need the result like this without duplicate dates
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select SUM(`rooms_qty`),`date`,`room_id` FROM table GROUP BY date;
```

Answer (score 1):

SUM is your friend. you also must enclose the field name **date** in backticks. date is a function!

```
SELECT
    SUM(rows_qty) AS rows_qty
    , `date`
    , room_id
FROM
    yourTable;
```